The meaning of Dammesek Eliezer
Usually the meaning of דמשק אליעזר is translated as Dammesek Eliezer, meaning that he was from the city Damascus in Syria as in Bereshis 15:2 Targum Onkelos and Radak.

וַיֹּ֣אמֶר אַבְרָ֗ם אֲדֹנָ֤י יֱהוִה֙ מַה־תִּתֶּן־לִ֔י וְאָנֹכִ֖י הוֹלֵ֣ךְ עֲרִירִ֑י וּבֶן־מֶ֣שֶׁק בֵּיתִ֔י ה֖וּא דַּמֶּ֥שֶׂק אֱלִיעֶֽזֶר׃
But Avram said, “O Lord Hashem, what can You give me, seeing that I shall die childless, and the one in charge of my household is Dammesek Eliezer!”
Onkelos also translates it in this sense when writing דמשקאה “from Damascus.” It is also possible that the servant’s name was Damessek  when he came to Avram, and that his master changed his name to Eliezer, seeing that this is a Hebrew name.

The discussion on the site about the Eliezer's family background, makes it unlikely to assume that Eliezer was from Damascus.  Nevertheless, the etymology of the city name Damascus, דר משק, means a plentifully watered place. Could one suppose by analogy that Dammesek refers to Eliezer's primary responsibility to provide water for Avraham's household? Is there a source for it? Is there a connection between בֶן־מֶ֣שֶׁק / manager and Aramaic דַּמֶּ֥שֶׂק with שׂ replacing שׁ due to Eliezer's pronunciation?
If so, it could explain why Avraham was not afraid to send Eliezer with many camels carrying gifts, as Eliezer was highly skilled at finding wells in unfamiliar places, such as Aram Naharaim.

Linguist R' Prof. Yoel Elitzur believes that the name of Damascus isn't Semitic in origin. But I myself like your idea for a chiddush on Eliezer.

@Harel13 Thank you. In Syria and Turkey the city Damascus is known as as-Sam for jasmine. Maybe there was some disagreement on whether to read left to right or right to left, the middle two letters in דמשק when reading left-to-right are SM. Maybe it is a reverted name?

I'm not an expert but he goes through each letter and argues for its originality. According to him the Resh evolved (or perhaps devolved) from the double Mem (in cuneiform)/Mem with dagesh (in alphabetic sources).

Another note is that Damascus wasn't originally settled by Arameans, so a non-Aramaic etymology is sensible (though that doesn't invalidate the possibility completely).

@Harel13 there are speculations that Arameans were Armenians, who used both  Semitic and Indoeuropean languages. Aram is a common Armenian name. https://allinnet.info/history/the-armenian-origins-of-the-aramaic-language/

Chazal’s interpretation of דולה ומשקה מתורת רבו could support the idea that Avram is using Eliezer’s birthplace (as well as his position in the household) as a pun of sorts referencing his talent.

@Yø-cRo Thanks. Please expand on it and it will be a good answer as it includes the specific meaning that I was making (I forgot this aggada). However, I think (and so does the comment of Harel13) the name of the city Damascus is very likely to be unrelated to Hebrew משק, or rather it is folk-etymology.

Would you take alternative explanations as to what damessek means? (Besides for being his birthplace, I mean)

@Loani of course!

Rashi on the posuk gives 3 possible explanations of dammesek, which are in the question and answers here

The gemara in Yoma (28b) states:

אֱלִיעֶזֶר עֶבֶד אַבְרָהָם, זָקֵן וְיוֹשֵׁב בִּישִׁיבָה הָיָה, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: ״וַיֹּאמֶר אַבְרָהָם אֶל עַבְדּוֹ זְקַן בֵּיתוֹ הַמֹּשֵׁל בְּכׇל אֲשֶׁר לוֹ״, אָמַר רַבִּי אֶלְעָזָר: שֶׁמּוֹשֵׁל בְּתוֹרַת רַבּוֹ. ״הוּא דַּמֶּשֶׂק אֱלִיעֶזֶר״ — אָמַר רַבִּי אֶלְעָזָר: שֶׁדּוֹלֶה וּמַשְׁקֶה מִתּוֹרָתוֹ שֶׁל רַבּוֹ לַאֲחֵרִים.
Eliezer, servant of Abraham, was an Elder and sat in yeshiva, as it is stated: “And Abraham said to his servant, the elder of his household, who ruled over all he had” (Genesis 24:2). Rabbi Elazar said: The verse means that he had mastery over the Torah of his master, having gained proficiency in all of the Torah of Abraham. That is the meaning of the verse: “He is Damascus [Dammesek] Eliezer” (Genesis 15:2). Rabbi Elazar said: The word Dammesek is a contraction of he who draws [doleh] and gives drink [mashke] to others from his master’s Torah.

Based on this, it is reasonable to suggest that Avraham is using Eliezer’s birthplace (regardless of its original etymology) as a play-on-words referencing his talent. Similarly, the rather unusual phrase Avraham uses for “the one in charge of my household” (בן משק ביתי) can be interpreted in the same vein.

In Bereishis (14:15), while describing Avraham's fight against the four kings, it says:

ויחלק עליהם לילה הוא ועבדיו ויכם וירדפם עד חובה אשר משמאל לדמשק
At night, he and his servants deployed against them and defeated them; and he pursued them as far as Hobah, which is north of Damascus.

The Ha'emek Davar explains this passuk based on the midrash that Avraham's 'servants' is actually just referring to Eliezer, and says:

וירדפם עד חובה וכו' החיל שלא הוכו ונזדרזו לברוח. רדפו עליהם אנשי אברם גם לחו"ל עד חובה. [ולפרש"י דחובה הוא דן אינו מובן הפי' אשר לשמאל לדמשק]. ומש"ה נקרא דמשק אליעזר. משום דעד דן היה נקרא המלחמה על אברם. ומדן והלאה נקראת ע"ש אליעזר. ודמשק היא העיר הראשית.
And he chased them until Chobah The soldiers that weren't killed, and hurried and ran away, Avraham's people chased them, even outside of Israel, until Chobah. [And according to Rashi's explanation, that Chobah is Dan, "North of Damascus" didn't make sense]. And this is why his name is Eliezer Damascus, because until Dan the battle was named for Avraham. But from Dan and on, it was named for Eliezer, and Damascus is the main city (in that area)

So Eliezer is given the name "Damascus" because of his part in Avraham's win in the fight which took place in its vicinity.
The reason that up until Dan that battle was named for Avraham, and afterwards it was named for Eliezer, can be found in an earlier Ha'emek Davar (14:14):

וירדף עד דן דן הוא בקצה גבול צפוני של א"י כידוע בגבולי יהושע ולא רצה אברם לרדוף אחריהם בעצמו חוץ לא"י
And he chased them until Dan. Dan is at the edge of the Northern border of the land of Israel, as is known from the borders in Yehoshua, and Avram didn't want to chase them, himself, outside of Israel.

Meaning, Avraham didn't want to leave Israel, even in order to chase the kings, so instead he sent his servants (meaning, based on the midrash, Eliezer). So while Avraham was fighting, the battle of named for him. Beyond that, it's named for Eliezer.

+1, although Avraham did leave during the famine. And the war was also a pikuach nefesh (to save Lot).

@Harel13 see the machlokes Rashi ramban by the famine, they seem to argue whether leaving was the right thing to do. Also, saving Lot might have happened earlier (this is conjecture, but if the kings were retreating I'd expect them to leave anything that would slow them down behind, ie loot/ people). So maybe Avraham had already gotten Lot out and they just continued fighting to make sure the kings didn't come back or something.
